# Convert COUNT(*) query result to .NET data type

Tags: .net, informix, sqldatatypes

I'm using Informix .NET Client SDK to run a simple SQL query counting items in a DB view, and use the query's result in C# code:

```
IfxConnection conn = ...;
var cmd = new IfxCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myview", conn);
IfxDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    object val = dr.GetValue(0);
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(val);
}
```

Which works fine, but I guess it should be possible to retrieve the number directly from the DataReader without the .NET conversion. I tried the following:

```
int count = dr.GetInt16(0);
int count = dr.GetInt32(0);
long count = dr.GetInt64(0);
```

All of those fail with an `InvalidCastException`. Does anybody know which data type a `COUNT(*)` query returns, and which .NET data type can be used to represent this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value stored in the `val` object will be a boxed instance of whatever the type is, put a break point on the line below `int count...` and inspect the `val` variable to find out.

Comment: How could I miss that - turns out it's a `Decimal`. Thanks for the quick help!